# Где хранить состояние текстов для сайтов для разных локалей?

Tags: локализация, i18n, frontend, интернационализация

Вроде хранят в файлах i18n
Но я не понимаю границ этой абстракции.

Я раньше думал, что все эти файлы **просто переводы от единственного источника правды основного языка** (en или ru).
Например, если автоперевод в системе CI то он переведет всё.

А если отличаются текстом локали, и **править точечно файлы разных локалей - то автоперевод не сделать, т.к. нет источника правды.**

Comment: Во-первых, автоперевод — страшное зло, все нормальные проекты переводятся строго вручную. Во-вторых, я что-то не понял вашей проблемы: почему ваши локали «отличаются текстом» и что вам мешает объявить какой-нибудь один источник правды?

Comment: @andreymal ну даже если не автоперевод, а система автоперевода, тобишь flow такой 
если изменяется i18n/file_name.ru.js то файл отправляется на перевод и в остальные файлы i18n/file_name.en.js, i18n/file_name.pl.js, ... добавляется/изменяется перевод

А если править каждый файл точечно, например i18n/file_name.pl.js, то изменения перезатрутся переводом от .ru.

Comment: Кто, как и почему их перезатрёт? Всё ещё не понимаю вашей проблемы. При нормальном ручном переводе переводчики получают уведомление, что в «источнике правды» добавилась/изменилась фраза и требуется обновить остальные файлы переводов, и переводчики их вручную обновляют

Comment: @andreymal к примеру
была фраза "Мы предоставляем услуги калькулятора" для РУ, а для польского изменили "Мы топ 1 среди конкурентов" по-польски.
Переводчики переводят "Мы предоставляем услуги калькулятора" и непонятно что выбирать, перевод "Мы предоставляем услуги калькулятора" или имеющийся  "Мы топ 1 среди конкурентов" по-польски.

Comment: Видимо, вы используете переводы не по назначению, потому что это, ну, уже не переводы)

Comment: так это было в вопросе.

Где хранить состояние текстов если они различаются